# ImageSwitcher image won't display onCreate()

Tags: android, imageswitcher

I can't figure out why my `ImageSwitcher` won't display the image when the Activity first loads.  I've set the image resource in the `onCreate` method but the image seems to be invisible until I start the animation. The animation should slide one image out and a second image in. When I click the button to start the animation, I can see the original image slide out from where it should be but I can't see it at the start. I've tried setting the image within the `ViewFactory` and just outside but it doesn't seem to work

Here's my `imageSwitcher` code:

```
mImageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
    mImageSwitcher.setOnClickListener(mImageSwitcherClickListener);

    mImageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            ImageView view = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            view.setLayoutParams(new
                    ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.image);
            return view;
        }
    });
    mImageSwitcher.setImageResource(R.mipmap.image);
```

Here is the layout for the Activity:

```
<ImageSwitcher
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:scaleX="4"
    android:scaleY="4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:animateFirstView="true"/>
```

Comment: why are you using mipmap use R.drawable.image

Comment: I just looked up the difference between the 2 folders....I didn't realize there was a difference

Comment: give it a try if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tutorials it shows you have to use animation

try this

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
```

reference from this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imageswitcher.htm)